# Is it possible to create a txt file directly on ipfs from a solidity function?

Tags: solidity, erc-721, ipfs

Here is my problem :

I have an ERC721 contract where I mint NFTs. My NFT represent a watch and I need to create a little .txt file that serves as a certificate for the watch. Said certificate must be stored on IPFS

So is it possible in my contract when I mint the NFT to create a little .txt file on IPFS and link it to my NFT ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a NodeJS bot that listens to NFT mint events to produce those receipts on IPFS. Ethereum has no knowledge of the existence of IPFS, those are inherently separate systems.